# Why is my date calculation not displaying anything?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm trying to use c# to get the number of days in-between two dates.

Here is my little program:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime futureDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(3);
            int daysBetween = (int)Math.Round((futureDate - today).TotalDays);
            
            Console.WriteLine("Date testing\n\n");
        
            Console.WriteLine("Today: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm}", today);
            Console.WriteLine("futureDate: {0:MM/dd/yy H:mm}", futureDate);
            Console.WriteLine("daysBetween: ", daysBetween);
    }
}
```

This is what I am getting.

```
Date testing
 
 
Today: 04/01/22 14:10 
futureDate: 04/04/22 0:00 
dateNumber:
```

For some reason, `dateNumber` is blank, but I am expecting it to be 3.

Is there a way to get that number?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried ` Console.WriteLine("daysBetween: " +  daysBetween);`

Comment: You did not include a hole to be replaced in the template string.

Comment: Typo?  There's no format placeholder in the `daysBetween` output: `"daysBetween: {0}"`  (And there's no `dateNumber` output at all...)

Comment: and there's not "dateNumber" outputed but it's show in the result...

Comment: @David no I'm just dumb, thankfully MD. RAKIB HASAN helped me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing a formatted string. The {0} means to insert the first parameter following the format string;

```
 Console.WriteLine("daysBetween: {0} ", daysBetween);
```